# Unable to play a very simple tone

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation

I was following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958750/avaudioplayernode-doesnt-play-sound), but the tone that I try to play with an AVAudioPCMBuffer does not play. The code is pretty simple:

```
class Player: NSObject {
    var engine = AVAudioEngine()
    var player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    var mixer: AVAudioMixerNode!
    var buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!

    override init() {
        mixer = engine.mainMixerNode
        buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: player.outputFormat(forBus: 0), frameCapacity: 100)
        buffer.frameLength = 100

        let sr = mixer.outputFormat(forBus: 0).sampleRate
        let nChannels = mixer.outputFormat(forBus: 0).channelCount

        var i = 0
        while i < Int(buffer.frameLength) {
            let val = sin(441 * Double(i) * Double.pi / sr)
            buffer.floatChannelData?.pointee[i] = Float(val * 0.5)
            i += Int(nChannels)
        }

        engine.attach(player)
        engine.connect(player, to: mixer, format: player.outputFormat(forBus: 0))

        engine.prepare()
    }

    func play() {
        do {
            try engine.start()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        player.scheduleBuffer(buffer, at: nil, options: .loops) {
            print("Played!")
        }

        player.play()
    }
}
```

For some reason, though, the iPhone does not make any sound. In my ViewController, I have this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var player = Player()

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        player.play()
    }

}
```

As you can see, `player` is a class variable, so it should not be deallocated from memory.

**When I run the app on my physical device (iPhone 6s iOS 11), it does not work, yet it does work on the simulator.** Why is this not making any sound, and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for me your code it's working fine, I mean I can hear the sound

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini, which device and iOS? I'm on hardware running iOS 11 full volume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your device is not on silent mode.

I just created a project that you can download for testing by yourself: https://github.com/mugx/TestSound

Comment: It seems that it works fine on the Simulator, but *not* on the actual hardware. Any idea why? Might it work on your hardware but for some reason not mine?

Comment: @IHaveAQuestion I also tested on a physical device, please check the answer

Comment: and just in case, you was missing:  the super for 'override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)', then you can even upvote my answer :)